# Magento 2.0: Adding a static block in a page template

Tags: magento-2.0

I want to add static block in page (.phtml) template.

I followed these steps:-

Step1: Navigate to CONTENT >Blocks >Add New Block.

Step 2: Create a Static Block (My_block).

Now I want to add this Block in page template.

I want to do something like below:
$this->getLayout()->createBlock('cms/block')->setBlockId('your_block_id')->toHtml();

please let me know how to add this static block in my page (.phtml) template.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Display Static Block in Phtml file & CMS page**

**In XML File:**

```
<referenceContainer name="content">
    <block class="Magento\Cms\Block\Block" name="block_identifier">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="block_id" xsi:type="string">block_identifier</argument>
        </arguments>
    </block>
</referenceContainer>
```

**In Phtml File:**

```
<?php echo $block->getLayout()->createBlock('Magento\Cms\Block\Block')->setBlockId('block_identifier')->toHtml();?>
```

**In CMS Content:**

```
{{block class="Magento\\Cms\\Block\\Block" block_id="block_identifier"}}
```

Answer (score 0):

To add CMS block in to page:

Call into HTML Show/Hide Editor

use this Code

```
{{block class="Magento\\Cms\\Block\\Block" block_id="block_identifier"}}
```

Another Method is to call through Widgets:

In the Editor click on the **insert Widget** and fill out respective inputs.